# React removes spaces

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here is a list of span elements

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
```

And css style for those elements:

```
span{
  background: red;
}
```

The result looks different in React app and local html+css files.

Link to Codepan https://codepen.io/Letsrock/pen/morogX

As you can see on screenshots:

[image: React] 
[image: Codepan]

How to make React to show those spaces between elements?

This is React component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you include your react component please?

Comment: Please add your React.JS code.

Comment: Added code of react component. The App.css file is the same as code on Codepan

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour from React. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1643

You could add empty text space between each span.

```
<span>1</span>
{' '}
<span>2</span>
```

Comment: The problem is that in my real project I have a lot of elements where I need those spaces, and I is difficult to put them by hands

Comment: If u just want empty space, why not use margin?

Comment: Because templates for web-site weren't made on React, and I didn't know about this issue with white-spaces in React

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `App.css` should work

```
span {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

It uses `margin` to do the trick. Adjust its value as you need.

Comment: I know about this fix, and I have to add it to every component where I use inline-block, and there are too many components to fix them by hands

Comment: **where do you import App.css?** It should apply to all `span` component if you import it at your entry file `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in your `App.css` :

## Solution A :

[image]

```css
span {
  background: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
</div>
```

## Solution B :

[image]

```css
span {
  background: red;
}

span:before {
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span:before {
  content: " ";
}
```

or

```
span: {
margin-right:4px;
}
```